# only the last chunck of contents is returned

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

```
function curl_get($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        print_r(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD));

        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
}
```

I was trying to match a string against this page "wikipedia.sfstate.us/Scarves". I use the function to get the content:

```
$url = "http://wikipedia.sfstate.us/Scarves";
$html = curl_get($url);
var_dump($html);
```

The result looks like this:

```
812 //CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD
string(812) "..." //$html string where the content is stored
```

However, the whole file is 64612 bytes (results by web-sniffer.net). And 64612 = 1024 * 63 + 812. That is to say, **I'm only getting the last 812 bytes of the file.**

Why could this happen? Any ideas on how to get the whole content? Thanks.

P.S.: I also tried sth. as below but doesn't help

```
if(strlen($html) < 1024){
    $html = '';
    $i = 0;
    while($content = file_get_contents($url, FILE_TEXT,  NULL, $i, $i + 1023)){
            $html .= $content;
            $i += 1023;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The page you are trying to scrape has a protection based on the user-agent. Add a proper user agent to your request and it works:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.79 Safari/537.1");
```

Of course if they have such a protection, it's probably because they don't want you to scrape their content.

Answer (score 0):

try this this is my tested code it is working fine

output:- [image]

```
<?php

function curl_get($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.79 Safari/537.1");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        print_r(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD));

        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
}


$url = "http://wikipedia.sfstate.us/Scarves";
$html = curl_get($url);
var_dump($html);
```

**Also try another example**

```
$ch = curl_init("http://wikipedia.sfstate.us/Scarves");
$fp = fopen("example_htmlpage.html", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```